# exibição de fotos pelo Repeater com sql server Usando split

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, imagem

Não estou conseguindo carregar as fotos no repiter fazendo um carrosel vindo do banco de daddos, não encontro nada na web referente a esse problema 
segue o cod
        ASPX ImovelDetalhe

```
              <section class="slider-container">
        <ul id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
            <li class="slide-current">
                <asp:Repeater ID="RptImg" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Fotos" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem  %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <div class="shadow">
        </div>
        <ul id="slider-controls" class="slider-controls"></ul>
    </section>
```

CS Imovel detalhe

```
      private void carregarInformacoes()
    {
        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Imovel/"));
        List<ListItem> images= new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
        {
        }
       RptImg.DataSource = images;
        RptImg.DataBind();

        int codigoImovel = 0;
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["IdImovel"], out codigoImovel);

        _imovelBo = new ImovelBo();
        var imovel = _imovelBo.ObterDetalhe(codigoImovel);

        if (imovel != null)
        {
            lblDescricao.Text = imovel.Obs;
            lblOperacao.Text = imovel.DescricaoOperacao;
            lblCidade.Text = imovel.DescricaoCidade;
            lblLocalizacao.Text = imovel.DescricaoLoc;
            lblTipoImovel.Text = imovel.DescricaoTipo;
            lblQtDormitorios.Text = imovel.QntQuarto.ToString();
            lblValor.Text = imovel.Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");
        }
    }
```

aonde é inserido no banco de dados as informações e as Imagens

```
          protected void btnSalvarImovel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (fuFotos.HasFile == false)
            lblImovel.Text = "Por favor selecione uma foto!";
        else
        {
            List<string> nomeFoto = new List<string> ();
            var arquivos = fuFotos.PostedFiles;
            foreach (var arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                string nomeArquivo = arquivo.FileName;
                fuFotos.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Imovel/" + nomeArquivo);
                nomeFoto.Add(nomeArquivo);
            }

            string comandoSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Imovel Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')",
                ddlCidade.SelectedItem.Value, ddlLocalizacao.SelectedItem.Value, ddlOperacao.SelectedItem.Value, ddlTipoImovel.SelectedItem.Value,
                txtTitulo.Text, txtObservacao.Text, txtValor.Text, txtQtdQuartos.Text, string.Join(",", nomeFoto));

            lblImovel.Text = "Imóvel cadastrado com sucesso!";
 try
            {
                conexaoSQL.Open();
                int teste = new SqlCommand(comandoSQL, conexaoSQL).ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conexaoSQL.Close();
            }
```

o que poderia ser feito para que possa chamar as imagens no reapeter?

Answer (score 0):

No método `carregarInformacoes()` você está carregando os valores do caminho completo em um array, depois está criando uma Lista de `ListItem`, que você não está carregando, e depois está chamando essa lista.

Ao invés de se matar fazendo tudo isso, o que você pode fazer é chamar o array como DataSource do repeater.

```
RptImg.DataSource = filesindirectory.Select(x=> new{ Value = x }).ToList();
```

É necessário incluir `using System.Linq;` no começo da página.

O motivo de carregar assim é que o objeto `String` contém apenas um atributo, que é o `Length`, para mostrar o valor da variável é necessário fazer desse jeito, onde é criado um objeto anônimo com um atributo (o valor).

No lugar de colocar `<%# Container.DataItem  %>`, coloque `<%# Eval("Value") %>`